# How do I get video ID's in a channel using Youtube API?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I need to get all video ID's in a channel.
I've tried as much as I could on the google APIs explorer but I couldn't find out what I want.
So is it possible to get all videos in a channel?
If yes, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

look at the url for the video it should look something like this

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkyA9wkAazE

the video id can be found at the end of the url. in the above example that is

> JkyA9wkAazE